# R - if row contains x print column header in new column

Tags: r, dataframe, header, row

I am new to R and programming in general. I have a very large data frame containing binary data. I want to read across the rows and where there is a 1 print the column name in a new column at the end. When there are multiple 1's across a row, I would like all of the column headers to be concatenated into a long comma separated list. To explain this better, see the test data frame below:

```
B <- data.frame(A = c(0, 1, 1, 0), 
            B = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

  A B
1 0 0
2 1 1
3 1 0
4 0 1
```

The output I want to generate would be:

```
  A B   C
1 0 0 
2 1 1   A, B
3 1 0   A
4 0 1   B
```

Where a new column 'C' is created and the column headers for the rows which contain 1 are added to a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$C <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(names(df)[as.logical(x)], collapse = ","))

#  A B   C
#1 0 0    
#2 1 1 A,B
#3 1 0   A
#4 0 1   B
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (will accept as correct answer after timer)

Answer (score 0):

We can use a vectorized approach  with `gsub`

```
trimws(gsub("^NA,*|,*\\s+NA$", "", do.call(paste, 
      c(as.data.frame( `dim<-`(names(B)[(NA^(B==0))*col(B)], dim(B))), sep=", "))))
#[1] ""     "A, B" "A"    "B"
```